# What does this Objective-C dictionary code do?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * products;  //not synthesized in .m
```

.m

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)
    {
        IAPProduct * product = _products[skProduct.productIdentifier];
        product.skProduct = skProduct;
        product.availableForPurchase = YES;
    }

    for (NSString * invalidProductIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        IAPProduct * product = _products[invalidProductIdentifier];
        product.availableForPurchase = NO;
        NSLog(@"Invalid product identifier, removing: %@", invalidProductIdentifier);
    }

    NSMutableArray * availableProducts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (IAPProduct * product in _products.allValues) {
        if (product.availableForPurchase) {
            [availableProducts addObject:product];
        }
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, availableProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;      
}
```

I'm having trouble with the line below:

```
IAPProduct * product = _products[skProduct.productIdentifier];
```

I'm thinking we are setting Type `IAPProduct *product= NSMutableDictionary[NSArray.productIdentifier];`

I thought Array's only have elements (`objectAtIndex`)? Why is there a dot (.) and the productIdentifier?

Also

Comment: That's the same as `IAPProduct *product = [_products objectForKey:[skProduct productIdentifier]];`

Comment: Thanks.  What's the value for objectForkey? if it's being treated as a dictionary, then why is it being treated as an array here:  IAPProduct * product = _products[invalidProductIdentifier]; <- what's the object and value here?

Comment: There is no array. This is modern Objective-C syntax. If `_products` is an `NSDictionary` then the value in the square brackets is a key in the dictionary. If `_product` were an `NSArray` then the value in the square brackets must be a valid array index.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble understanding how can we assign an instance of a class as objectForKey ?

Comment: See my answer for a clearer breakdown of what I've described so far in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble understanding this line:

```
IAPProduct * product = _products[skProduct.productIdentifier];
```

Lets break it down:

```
NSString *key = skProduct.productIdentifier;
IAPProduct * product = _products[key];
```

The 2nd line is modern syntax for:

```
IAProduct * product = [_products objectForKey:key];
```

This is the normal way to lookup a value in a dictionary for a given key.

Comment: Thank you. How can we assign an instance of IAProduct an objectForkey.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. `objectForKey:` is a method on the `NSDictionary` class. Step back. Your `_products` dictionary (which you never show how it was populated or setup) appears to contain a set of `IAPProduct` objects keyed off of `NSString` objects representing the product's identifier. When you call `_products[someIdentifier]` you are getting the `IAPProduct` with the given identifier.

Comment: I'm struggling with IAPProduct being a class, why is it being assigned an NSString. Typically an NSString is assigned like: classInstance.someVariable = aString;

Comment: A string is NOT being assigned to `product`. An `IAPProduct` from the dictionary is being assigned to `product`. Please read the docs on `NSDictionary`. Do you understand what you have put in your own `_products` dictionary? That seems to be the biggest issue here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `IAPProduct *product= NSMutableDictionary[NSArray.productIdentifier];`

The type of `skProduct` is `SKProduct`, not `NSArray`. The fast enumeration `for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)` loops through all elements in `skProducts` as `SKProduct`.

It's (to some extent) like using a loop with a counter doing:

```
//for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)
for (int i=0; i<skProducts.count; i++)
{
    SKProduct *skProduct = skProduct[i];
    IAPProduct * product = _products[skProduct.productIdentifier];
    product.skProduct = skProduct;
    product.availableForPurchase = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  SKProduct is a standard StoreKit class.  Another stupid question:  how can we assign an instance of SKProduct an element of an array?