# Objective-C: Code Clarification

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm having trouble understanding the code below:

```
for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts){
    IAPProduct * product = _products[skProduct.productIdentifier];
```

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * products;  //not synthesized in .m
```

.m

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)
    {
        IAPProduct * product = _products[skProduct.productIdentifier];
        product.skProduct = skProduct;
        product.availableForPurchase = YES;
    }
```

Q1.  SKProduct is an Apple StoreKit class.  How are we able to assign an element of skProducts array to an instance of SKProduct?  I thought we can only assign values to properties and IVARs?

Q2.  How are we able to create an Instance of IAPProduct and set it equal to _products[skProduct.productIdentifier], which I believe is just an NSString?

Let me know if you'd like to see .h and .m for IAAProduct.  Thanks

UPDATE: adding IAPProduct
.h

```
@class SKProduct;

@interface IAPProduct : NSObject

- (id)initWithProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier;
- (BOOL)allowedToPurchase;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL availableForPurchase;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * productIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKProduct * skProduct;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL purchaseInProgress;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL purchase;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation IAPProduct

- (id)initWithProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.availableForPurchase = NO;
        self.productIdentifier = productIdentifier;
        self.skProduct = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)allowedToPurchase {
    if (!self.availableForPurchase) return NO;

    if (self.purchaseInProgress) return NO;

    if (self.purchase) return NO;

    return YES;
}

@end
```

UPDATE 2:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler) (BOOL success, NSArray *products);
@interface IAPHelper : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *products;

-(id)initWithProducts:(NSMutableDictionary *)products;
-(void)requestProductsWithProductIdentifiers:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHander;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import "IAPProduct.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>


@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate>
@end

@implementation IAPHelper
{
    SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
    RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;
}

-(id)initWithProducts:(NSMutableDictionary *)products
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _products = products;
    }
}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHander
{
    // 4
    _completionHandler = [completionHander copy];

    NSMutableSet *productsIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:_products.count];
    for(IAPProduct *product in _products.allValues)
    {
        product.availableForPurchase = NO;
        [productsIdentifiers addObject:product.productIdentifier];
    }

    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                        initWithProductIdentifiers:productsIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];
}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    // 1
    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)
    {
        IAPProduct * product = _products[skProduct.productIdentifier];
        product.skProduct = skProduct;
        product.availableForPurchase = YES;
    }

    // 2
    for (NSString * invalidProductIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        IAPProduct * product = _products[invalidProductIdentifier];
        product.availableForPurchase = NO;
        NSLog(@"Invalid product identifier, removing: %@", invalidProductIdentifier);
    }

    // 3
    NSMutableArray * availableProducts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (IAPProduct * product in _products.allValues) {
        if (product.availableForPurchase) {
            [availableProducts addObject:product];
        }
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, availableProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Re: Q1,why wouldn't you be able to assign an `SKProduct` object to an `SKProduct` variable? Why does it make a difference if it's from an array or not? That is, what about this specific assignment is giving you trouble? Re: Q2, What's `IAPProduct`? Are you asking how you can instantiate one? Or asking why you're able to treat an `NSString` as an `IAPProduct`? Is `IAPProduct` an `NSString` subclass or something?

Comment: Thanks.  Q1:  all the elements of response.products are instances of SKProduct? Q2: I updated the Question with .h and .m of IAAProduct.  I'm struggling with IAPProduct being a class, why is it being assigned an NSString.  Typically an NSString is assigned like: classInstance.someVariable = aString;

Comment: Why are you repeating your [earlier question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578750/what-does-this-objective-c-dictionary-code-do)?

Comment: Well, I didn't think I had asked the last question with clarity.  With this question, I included IAPProduct.h &.m.  Instead of keep dragging in the comments, I thought I'll ask a more concise question and also include IAPProduct.h.  I'm still struggling with the answer.  Can we continue here?

Comment: I'm thinking "Objective-C code clarification" is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1. SKProduct is an Apple StoreKit class. How are we able to assign an element of skProducts array to an instance of SKProduct? I thought we can only assign values to properties and IVARs?

Not sure if I understand that question correctly. Are you referring to the `for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)` line? In that case, `skProduct` is a *local* loop variable. It uses fast enumeration to iterate over all elements in the array. The loop body will be executed once for each element in the array. In each iteration, a different element in the array is assigned to`skProduct` (which is then used in the loop body).

> Q2. How are we able to create an Instance of IAPProduct and set it equal to _products[skProduct.productIdentifier], which I believe is just an NSString?

`skProduct.productIdentifier` is a string, but it's not assigned to an `IAPProduct` variable. The string is just used as a key in the `_products` dictionary (which corresponds to the `products` property declared in the header). You could also write it like this:

```
IAPProduct * product = [self.products objectForKey:skProduct.productIdentifier];
```

Comment: Thanks you.  Q1:  So does that mean all the elements of response.products are instances of SKProduct?

Comment: Q2:  I thought an instance of a class would be instantiated as: IAPProduct *product = [IAPProduct alloc]init;  So how is it being instantiated with a key?

Comment: Q1: Yes, the documentation about the `products` property of `SKProductsResponse` explicitly states that ["the array consists of a list of SKProduct objects."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsResponse/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProductsResponse/products).

Comment: Q2: It's not instantiated there, that has happened earlier (not shown in your code), before the instance was put into the dictionary. The code here is just getting an already-existing instance from the dictionary.

Comment: Okay, I understand SKProducts.  Just some more clarification on product (sorry, I'm sort of new).  Please see update 2.  Can you please point out where the instance of IAPProduct *product is being instantiated.  Also, if it has instantiated earlier, why is the syntax IAPProduct *product = ... ?  Thanks

Comment: As I said, it comes from the dictionary. That dictionary is apparently passed to `initWithProducts:` from elsewhere. If the syntax for a simple variable assignment isn't clear to you, you should perhaps start with something simpler... I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the difference between instantiation and assignment.